# How to write more simple variable-step Runge Kutta algorithm to solve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, homework

Here is a case of Runge Kutta algorithm with variable-step size:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
x[0] = 0;
y[0] = 1.;
ε = 0.01;(*Maximum allowable error*)
L = 0.1;(*Initial step size*)
f[x_, y_] := x^2
SingleRK[u_, v_, L_ : 0.1] := 
 Module[{x = u, y = v, h = L, K1, K2, K3, K4, ynext, xnext}, 
  K1 = f[x, y];
  K2 = f[x + h/2, y + h*K1/2];
  K3 = f[x + h/2, y + h*K2/2];
  K4 = f[x + h, y + h*K3];
  ynext = y + h/6 (K1 + 2 K2 + 2 K3 + K4);
  xnext = x + h;
  Return[{xnext, ynext}]]
LocalRK[{u_, v_}] := 
 Module[{xnext, xinitial, ynext, yinitial, x, y, h = L}, x = u; y = v;
  {xnext, ynext} = SingleRK[x, y, h];
  If[Abs[ynext - y] < ε, 
   While[Abs[ynext - y] < ε, h = 2 h;
    ynext = SingleRK[x, y, h] // Last;], 
   While[Abs[ynext - y] > ε, h = h/2;
    ynext = SingleRK[x, y, h] // Last;]];
  {x + h, ynext}]
data = NestList[LocalRK, {x[0], y[0]}, 35];
Abs /@ Subtract @@@ 
  Partition[data[[;; , 1]], 2, 1](*Step-size information*)
Show[Plot[1/3 (x^3 + 3), {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Red}],
  ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.01]}]]
data
```

But I found that the error of the first step was obviously more than `0.01`, but it did not automatically adjust to the appropriate step size. **How to improve this problem(I need the step size of each step to ensure that the error is exactly less than 0.01 in the maximum step size)?**

Then I need more concise examples of variable-step algorithm for solving definite integral or differential equations.

I hope to get more adaptive step size algorithms to solve the following differential equation:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Why not use `NDSolve`?

Comment: @ChrisK I want to use a specific numerical algorithm to solve this problem. This is an exercise in numerical analysis.

Comment: It is also possible to define user methods for `NDSolve`, see tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns

Comment: @I.M. Thank you for your comments. I need to use specific numerical algorithms to solve differential equations. This is required for homework.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the error of the first step less than `0.01`, we can solve this problem with the help of the intermediate variable `sol`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
x[0] = 0;
y[0] = 1.;
ε = 0.01;
L = 0.1;
f[x_, y_] := x^2
SingleRK[u_, v_, L_ : 0.1] := 
 Module[{x = u, y = v, h = L, K1, K2, K3, K4, ynext, xnext}, 
  K1 = f[x, y];
  K2 = f[x + h/2, y + h*K1/2];
  K3 = f[x + h/2, y + h*K2/2];
  K4 = f[x + h, y + h*K3];
  ynext = y + h/6 (K1 + 2 K2 + 2 K3 + K4);
  xnext = x + h;
  Return[{xnext, ynext}]]
LocalRK[{u_, v_}] := 
 Module[{xnext, xinitial, ynext, yinitial, x, y, h = L, sol}, x = u; y = v;
  {xnext, ynext} = SingleRK[x, y, h];
  If[Abs[ynext - y] < ε, 
   While[Abs[ynext - y] < ε, h = 2 h;
    ynext = SingleRK[x, y, h] // Last; sol = SingleRK[x, y, h/2];], 
   While[Abs[ynext - y] > ε, h = h/2;
    ynext = SingleRK[x, y, h] // Last; sol = SingleRK[x, y, h];]];
  sol]
data = NestList[LocalRK, {x[0], y[0]}, 35];
Abs /@ Subtract @@@ 
  Partition[data[[;; , 1]], 2, 1](*Step-size information*)
Show[Plot[1/3 (x^3 + 3), {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Red}],
  ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.01]}]]
data
```

But the logic of this algorithm is not very clear. I hope community members can provide more and more sophisticated algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Runge-Kutta-Felberg variable-step method:

```
RKF[f_, x0_, y0_, xmax_, hmax_, hmin_, eps_] := 
 Module[{x = x0, y = y0, pts = {{x0, y0}}, K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, 
   delta, h = hmax, flag = 1, R}, 
  While[flag == 1, K1 = h*f[x, y]; K2 = h*f[x + h/4, y + 1/4*K1]; 
   K3 = h*f[x + 3 h/8, y + 3/32*K1 + 9/32*K2]; 
   K4 = h*f[x + 12 h/13, 
      y + 1932/2197*K1 - 7200/2197*K2 + 7296/2197*K3]; 
   K5 = h*f[x + h, y + 439/216*K1 - 8*K2 + 3680/513 K3 - 845/4104 K4];
    K6 = h*f[x + h/2, 
      y - 8/27*K1 + 2*K2 - 3544/2565 K3 + 1859/4104 K4 - 11/40*K5]; 
   R = Abs[K1/360 - 128/4275 K3 - 2197/75240 K4 + K5/50 + 2/55 K6]/h; 
   If[R <= eps, 
    y = y + (16/135 K1 + 6656/12825 K3 + 28561/56430 K4 - 9/50 K5 + 
        2/55 K6); x = x + h; AppendTo[pts, {x, y}]]; 
   delta = 0.84 (eps/R)^(1/4); 
   Which[delta <= 0.1, h = 0.1 h, delta >= 4, h = 4 h, True, 
    h = h*delta]; If[h > hmax, h = hmax]; 
   If[x >= xmax, flag = 0, 
    If[x + h > xmax, h = xmax - x, 
     If[h < hmin, flag = 0; Print["minimum h exceeded"]]]]]; pts]

f[x_, y_] := y^2
RKF[f, 0, 1, 2, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01]
Differences[%[[All, 1]]](*Step-size information*)
```

Comment: All this is doable in `NDSolve` as @I.M. pointed out, though IIRC the step control depends on the order when it's not an embedded method.  In fact, for RK methods, you don't even need the plug-in framework.